# Pandas MappingDataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframes are like below:

```
Store  PG1       PG2              PG3                      PG4
500    1 Women   02 Shirts        02 S-S_Woven_Shirts      02 Checked-Striped-
552    2 Baby
600    4 Boys    00 Denim All
704    5 Girls   01 Jackets       15 Woven blouses, tops


Store      MinThreshold   MaxThreshold   PG1       PG2               PG3                      PG4   
552        0              10             2 Baby
552        2              15             2 Baby    00 Denim All
600        3              16             5 Girls
600        4              17             4 Boys    00 Denim All
704        5              18             5 Girls   01 Jackets        15 Woven blouses, tops
704        10             20             0 Men     00 Denim_Bottoms  02 Capris   
500        6              19             1 Women   02 Shirts         02 S-S_Woven_Shirts      02 Checked-Striped-Patterned_Shirts-Tops-Blouses
```

Desired output is;

```
Store  PG1      PG2             PG3                   PG4                 MinThreshold  MaxThreshold                    
500    1 Women  02 Shirts       02 S-S_Woven_Shirts   02 Checked-Striped- 6             19
552    2 Baby                                                             2             15
600    4 Boys   00 Denim All                                              4             17
704    5 Girls  01 Jackets      15 Woven blouses, tops                    5             18
```

I want to add the threshold values into first dataframe from second dataframe based on "Store", "PG1", "PG2", "PG3" and "PG4".

I tried this;

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left',
 left_on=["Store","PG1","PG2","PG3","PG4"], right_on =["Store","PG1","PG2","PG3","PG4"])
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Threshold values are being retrieved as "NaN" values.

Comment: I get NaN for the first row only which is correct as PG4 for store 500 is different in df1 and df2.